# Currency Converter In ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to include a live currency converter into my ionic application but cannot seem to find much information on how to go about this. Does anyone have any useful links or information i could use?

Answer (score 2):

To convert currencies there are many different services.

Here a service that allows to convert currencies http://fixer.io/.

To convert two currencies you have to make a GET:

GET http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,CHF

Result (json):

```
{
   "base":"EUR",
   "date":"2017-04-18",
   "rates":{
      "CHF":1.0686,
      "USD":1.0682
   }
}
```

Now use http object to call the service.